# resizing an image without compromising the aspect ratio

Tags: java, image, resize, bufferedimage, java-2d

I  use the following codes to resize an image but the problem is that they don't maintain the original aspect ratio, is there any way by which I can resize the image without compromising the aspect ratio.

```
BufferedImage img1 = new BufferedImage(800, 600,
                    BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
            img1.createGraphics()
                    .drawImage(
                            ImageIO.read(
                                    new File("/home/rvkydmpo/webapps/ROOT/images/profilePicture/"
                                            + fileName)).getScaledInstance(800,
                                    600, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH), 0, 0, null);
            ImageIO.write(img1, "jpg", new File("/home/rvkydmpo/webapps/ROOT/images/profilePicture/" +fileName));
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Resize image while keeping aspect ratio in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/991349/resize-image-while-keeping-aspect-ratio-in-java)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to read [the docs of `getScaledInstance()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Image.html#getScaledInstance%28int,%20int,%20int%29):

> ```
> Image java.awt.Image.getScaledInstance(int width, int height, int hints)
> ```
>
> Creates a scaled version of this image. A new Image object is returned
>   which will render the image at the specified width and height by
>   default. The new Image object may be loaded asynchronously even if the
>   original source image has already been loaded completely.
>
> **If either width or height is a negative number then a value is
>   substituted to maintain the aspect ratio of the original image
>   dimensions.** If both width and height are negative, then the original
>   image dimensions are used.

(emphasis mine)

Comment: How do I calculate the height and width in the `getScaledInstance` function so that it maintains the original aspect ratio.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know on what server you are running your code, but if you running it on linux based system you could use the imagemagick **convert** command.

There's also a java library available to call imagemaick it called [JMagick](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/jmagick/index.php?title=Main_Page)

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with a server. There's no need to use `imagemagick`. Java has the functionality he needs built-in.