# getting the desired aspect ratio for BufferedImage

Tags: java, image, bufferedimage, image-resizing, java-2d

I am using the following codes to resize an image, I can easily get same aspect ratio as the original image by using the `getScaledInstance` function by setting one parameter to negative, so that it automatically maintains the other paramter to get the aspect ratio. But the problem that I am facing is with the `BufferedImage`, I cannot set it to the desired aspect ratio because I don't know beforehand what values of height it will generate(width I have set to 500).I have also included the image that I can getting as a result of running the following code. `BufferedImage` I have set to 800x600 because I have no other option.My previous question was [resizing an image without compromising the aspect ratio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16546415/resizing-an-image-without-compromising-the-aspect-ratio)

```
public class ResizeImage {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedImage img1 = new BufferedImage(800, 600,
                BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        img1.createGraphics()
                .drawImage(
                        ImageIO.read(
                                new File(
                                        "C:/Users/Public/Pictures/Sample Pictures/Desert.jpg"))
                                .getScaledInstance(500, -1, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH),
                        0, 0, null);
        ImageIO.write(img1, "jpg", new File(
                "C:/Users/Public/Pictures/Sample Pictures/test/Desert.jpg"));



    }
}
```

[image: BufferedImage creating extra blank background]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the math to get the original image aspect ratio

```
double ratio = img1.getWidth() / img1.getHeigth();
```

and invoke the getScaledInstance with this ratio

```
blabla.getScaledInstance(500, (int)500 / ratio, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
```